# mysql : how to fillter the columns data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table "*matchdetail*":

| txtProjectdate | txtProjectGroup | txtMember |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01T00:00:00 | AMT | steve |
| 2022-03-01T00:20:00 | SSIT | Parvq |
| 2022-03-01T01:05:00 | AMT | Parvq |
| 2022-03-01T01:05:00 | VALOK | Shveas |
| 2022-03-01T01:05:00 | RPC | modi |
| 2022-03-01T01:05:00 | VALOK | khan |
| 2022-03-01T01:05:00 | AMT | lkhmi |
| 2022-03-01T01:05:00 | BIK | lkhmi |
| 2022-03-01T01:06:00 | AMT | steve |

And I required output as below:

| txtProjectGroup | Count | txtMember |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMT | 2 | steve |
| VALOK | 1 | Shveas |
| RPC | 1 | modi |
| VALOK | 1 | khan |
| SSIT | 1 | Parvq |
| BIK | 1 | lkhmi |
| AMT | 1 | Parvq |
| AMT | 1 | lkhmi |

Is it at all possible to receive result like below?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an aggregation function like [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count) and the `GROUP BY` clause to identify the fields you want to group on:

```
SELECT txtProjectGroup,
       txtMember,
       COUNT(txtProjectdate) AS cnt
FROM matchdetail
GROUP BY txtProjectGroup,
         txtMember
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j6EgvZ7pHpfVA7Up6tfc8A/0).